# deletedAt is not being set when using Sequelize paranoid attribute and FeathersJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, postman, feathersjs

`deletedAt` is not being set when using `paranoid` in my sequelized model. I'm using FeathersJS. Here is my `contacts` model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const contacts = sequelizeClient.define('contacts', {
    subjectId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    },
    indexes: [
      {
        fields: ['subjectId', 'phoneNumber'],
        unique:true
      }
    ],
  });
  contacts.associate = function (models) {};
  return contacts;
};
```

I'm building an API. Thus, I'm testing my routes using Postman. And when I delete the contact via Postman, the returned response doesn't set the date for `deleteAt`. It's still set as `null`. I looked at other examples in StackOverflow. The example models is a little different from this one and I can't figure out the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some of the example code you're using to delete rows

Comment: @AbirTaheer I'm using Postman to test my routes. So when I delete a contact via Postman, the deletedAt field is null. However, when I used the softDelete hook that FeathersJS provides, the deletedAt field gets set.
 
https://hooks-common.feathersjs.com/hooks.html#softdelete

Just wanted to try using the paranoid parameter cause it's cleaner and uses less code. :)

Comment: Do you simply call `destroy` on `contacts` model? Please add a piece of code where you're deleting an instance of contacts

Comment: When I make a delete request, FeathersJS is removing the contact for me in the background. No need to write any code. I guess ```paranoid``` doesn't work in this situation